# Unsupported culture code

Tags: c#, internationalization, cultureinfo

In my application I already am using a lot of culture codes, like de-DE, es-ES, cz-CZ etc.
All languages work correct. However, I get an error with the culture coe Lt-sr-SP (Serbian, Latin).

When I call:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo(Settings.Default.UI_Language);
```

where Settings.Default.UI_Language = "Lt-sr-SP" I get an error that the culture is unsupported, the culture code is an invalid culture code identification (in Dutch so I cannot really copy it here without making sense for most of you).

For all used language I have a dedicated string resource file, but I even checked with a language I don't have such a resource file made for, and I don't get the error in such case.

Comment: According to the .NET CultureInfo page, that is not the correct culture code, of which microsoft lists it as `sr-SP-Latn`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(vs.71).aspx

Comment: Maybe that list works too, but I used the culture name from the solution and list from http://techmantium.com/culture-codes/ now ... it works, but thanks for letting me know there are more (different) lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search the available cultures using the following code, you will find that the code you're looking for isn't in the set of available cultures.

```
var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Where(c => c.Name.Equals("Lt-sr-SP"));
```

If you search using

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Where(c => c.EnglishName.Contains("Serbian"));
```

You can see that the culture code you're looking for is sr-Latn-RS.

Comment: I indeed found a better link than the list I used before: http://techmantium.com/culture-codes/